# Map of hiking routes in the Polish Tatras?

Tags: hiking, maps, poland, tatras

Is there a map with hiking routes in Polish Tatras, preferably in English, with enough quality to be read, available on the Web?

I found a few maps but all of them are either too small or, when large enough to see the routes, unreadable.

Any other resources describing routes, and/or what can be found are welcome.

Comment: This question might be better asked on outdoor.se

Comment: What do you need to be in English and why? The legend is usually in English too, and with the geographic names, translation doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 13):

For anyone stumbling upon this question, or for your future hikes in Tatra Mountains.
I recommend this website: [mapa-turystyczna.pl](http://mapa-turystyczna.pl/)

It is in Polish only, but it uses interactive Google maps, which is self explanatory and great for planning routes. All you need to know is that:

- "z" means "from",
- "do" means "to",
- (and after clicking on a point) "ustaw jako początek trasy" is "set as starting point",
- "idź przez" is "go through" (set way point)
- "ustaw jako koniec trasy" is "set as end point"

Plus, they have mobile version so you can use it on a smartphone.

Answer (score 7):

I managed to find a very readable set of maps here:
http://www.e-gory.pl/mapy-online/tatry-compass/

but they are only in Polish I am afraid. The routes are marked in colour dashed lines (the colour corresponds to the colour of the signs marked on the trail), the other symbols used seem rather standard.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: https://mapa-turystyczna.pl/ - it has a map with all routes

Answer (score 0):

A good guide in English is [A Ceper’s guide to Tatra Mountains in Poland and Slovakia](https://przewodnik-po-gorach.pl/product/a-cepers-guide-to-tatra-mounatins-in-poland-and-slovakia/)